# Node: Twitter search api request issue

Tags: node.js, twitter-search, node-twitter

I am observing the wrong output while hitting Twitter search api and i am using [this npm module](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter).

I am passing `since`, `from`, `until` parameters to the api, but i am not getting any tweet where as generating the cURL request from the Twitter's oauth signature generator tool gives the correct response.
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/tools/signature-generator

```
var TWITTER_SEARCH = 'search/tweets';
twitter.get(TWITTER_SEARCH, { q: criteria }, function (err, result, response) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('Got %d tweets', result.statuses.length);
        return cb(err, result, response);
    })
```

I have supplied criteria in following ways"

- `from%3AJeffMcMahon_Chi since%3A2016-07-17 until%3A2016-07-20`
- `from%3AJeffMcMahon_Chi%20since%3A2016-07-17%20until%3A2016-07-20%20`

I always get 0 tweets whereas there exists tweets between these dates ( I am getting tweets through cURL request via Postman tool).

Received Response

```
{ statuses: [],
  search_metadata: 
   { completed_in: 0.02,
     max_id: 755754337922641900,
     max_id_str: '755754337922641920',
     query: 'from%253AJeffMcMahon_Chi%2520since%253A2016-07-17%2520until%253A2016-07-20%2520',
     refresh_url: '?since_id=755754337922641920&q=from%253AJeffMcMahon_Chi%2520since%253A2016-07-17%2520until%253A2016-07-20%2520&include_entities=1',
     count: 15,
     since_id: 0,
     since_id_str: '0' } }
```

Am i passing parameter in wrong format ? What should be the right format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the URI encoding from the criteria resolves the issue for me.

Now Criteria looks like

`from:my_screen_name since:2016-07-14 until:2016-07-18`